# Delete hostname HTTP client DNS cache and close connections to specific IP

Tags: http, go, dns

I'm using the `net/http` library to make HTTP requests.

I have a use case where sometimes I resolve a domain name that fronts an Amazon CloudFront distribution. Occasionally for reasons of its own, CloudFront will resolve the DNS to a point of presence (POP) on a different continent, resulting in very high latencies.

When this happens, I want to cause a "targeted reset" making my `http.Client` "forget" about that POP, basically closing open TCP connections and forcing the DNS for that hostname to be re-resolved.

I'm not able to find a way to force this "targeted reset". My options seem to be:

1. Close all idle connections in the `http.Transport` using [Transport.CloseIdleConnections()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport.CloseIdleConnections), but this will close *all* TCP connections *and* it won't do anything about cached DNS results.
2. Construct a whole new `http.Client`. I've confirmed this does result in re-doing the DNS lookup and it does also create a new connection pool. The downside is it forces re-resolution of all other DNS and force-closes all other TCP connections, even ones I like.

Is there a way to achieve the "targeted reset" (DNS for specific hostnames, TCP connections for specific IP addresses) I've described? I'm happy to use reflection and traverse down into the `http.Client` implementation to some extent.

Comment: Why does option 2 force close all other connections?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco because the connection pools are in the client, so replacing the client replaces the pools, and hence the connections in those pools.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco, yes exactly what @Adrian said. The new `http.Client` basically just starts a new pool. And presumably also a DNS cache.